AxiosError "Network Error" only happening on Google Chrome, not on Firefox
I have built a React app and in this React app I'm doing the following query to a published google sheet as a csv:
    const csvFromGsheets =
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSpTC66666666dK5CxSESrLJE_TGqTiwW666666666u69xwvI/pub?output=csv" //this is a fake sheet id

 axios
      .get(csvFromGsheets)
      .then((response) => {
        const parsedCsvData = parseCSV(response.data)
        setCsvData(parsedCsvData)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching CSV data:", error)
      })

This runs just fine in Firefox, while I develop it or in prod, but on Chrome (and sometimes in mobile phones too) I'm getting the following error:
Error fetching CSV data: AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_NETWORK"config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Network Error"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}stack: "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:176:14)\n    at Axios.request (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:54:41)"[[Prototype]]: Error

And an error just below:
net::ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED

I'm also providing a screenshot of the error here: :
Why? How can I fix it?
